# Regex match a CSV of alphanumeric and dash characters with minimum number of values and minimum value length

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to regex test a CSV string in JavaScript. The CSV is basically a list of article tags. Each tag can only contain lowercase letters, numbers, and hyphens. They also have to be 2-24 characters in length and there must be between 2 and 24 tags. The CSV must also NOT end with a comma.

Here are some examples of what I want to match and not match

```
one,two,three-3 //Should match
o,two,three //Not match
one,two,three, //Not match
one //Not match
one,,two,three //Not match
11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99,1010,1111,1212,1313,1414,1515,1616,1717,1818,1919,2020,2121,2222,2323,2424,2525 //Not match
1234567890123456789212345 //Not match(25 chars long)
one#,two,three //Not match
```

Here is that regex that I've come up with so far, but it's not quite there. It still matches the full string when the formatting is wrong, it just doesn't include the incorrect values.  Anybody have any ideas?

```
(([a-z0-9-]{2,24})(\,{0,1}){2,24}(.*(?<!,)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the regex pattern

```
^(?:[-a-z0-9]{2,24}(?:,(?=.)|$)){2,24}$
```

Test this regex [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/2h0ZKw/1).

Answer (score 0):

Use anchors:

```
^[a-z0-9-]{2,24}(?:,[a-z0-9-]{2,24}){1,23}$
```